# + Sign removal javascript

Tags: javascript, python, prototypejs

Hi I dont know why `+` sign is removed and how to eliminate it's removing.

Sample code is presented:

```
var customer_number = $('cust_num');
var l_sParams = 'number='+customer_number.value;
alert(l_sParams);

var l_sURL = '/caller/send_sms';   

new Ajax.Request(l_sURL, {parameters: l_sParams, method: 'POST', 
        onComplete:function(a_oRequest){    

    }.bind(this)
});
```

the alert displays ex: `+1907727500`

and if I print in Python it is printed without `+` sign like this ex:

```
_to_customer = self.request.post['number']
```

result: `1907727500` (without + )

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+` in a query parameter is the escape code for a space. You receive `' 1907727500'`, *with* the space.

Use `%2B` instead, or better still, have JavaScript quote your values properly

```
var l_sParams = 'number=' + encodeURIComponent(customer_number.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings containing a plus sign (or such special chars) should be urlencoded since it represents space in URLs.  Use encodeURI() to do that.